# pgfplots issues with fillbetween

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

With this example document

```
\documentclass[tikz,12pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12} 

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ 
    % error bars/y dir=both,
    error bars/y explicit, 
    ]

    \addplot[blue,name path=A,smooth] {x^2};
    \addplot[red,name path=B,smooth]  {x^2+1};
    \addplot[gray!50] fill between[of=A and B];

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture} 

\end{document}
```

the output looks as expected:
[image]

If I additionally add more data and enable the `error bars/y dir=both` the example fails to compile. Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: This is a bug, thanks for the report. I will take a note on my todo list.
A workaround could be to plot the same plot twice, once without error bar (but with `name path`) and once only with the error bar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug. Thanks to your report, I have identified and fixed it; will become part of pgfplots 1.13.

A workaround is to draw the path twice, once with `name path` and *without* `error bars` and once *without* `name path` but *with* `error bars`:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12} 

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ 
    error bars/y dir=both,
    error bars/y fixed=1, 
    ]

    \addplot[blue,smooth] {x^2};
    \addplot[red,smooth]  {x^2+1};
    \addplot[draw=none,error bars/y dir=none,name path=A,smooth] {x^2};
    \addplot[draw=none,error bars/y dir=none,name path=B,smooth]  {x^2+1};
    \addplot[gray!50] fill between[of=A and B];

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture} 

\end{document}
```

[image]